# Vista won't let me save a backup of applicationHost.config

Tags: windows-vista, security, permissions, administrator

I am trying to make some changes in the applicationHost.config file on Windows Vista, and an important step is to back the file up in case I screw it up.  Well, it won't let me save a copy in the

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\config\

folder!

I get the following error:

```
C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config.bak
You don’t have permission to save in this location. 
Contact the administrator to obtain permission.

Would you like to save in the [loggedinuser] folder instead?
```

I'd contact the administrator, except for the fact that I am him!  That is to say that the account I am using is the Administrator account.  I don't know for sure how to give myself permission to save stuff in this folder.  I tried to give myself permission to be able to what I needed, but it told me Access Denied.  The folder properties says that the members of the Administrators group has full control, and when I look at my user account it says that I am an Administrator.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right click the executable of your editor, such as notepad.exe and select "run as administrator."  This will give you the permissions needed to modify and save the file in protected areas of the filesystem.  FYI - This will not work on shortcuts!

extra:  You can do this for the CMD prompt too.

Comment: Yes, I've heard of this, but just didn't think of it.  Highly annoying, because I need this kind of thing so seldom.  First time I've had to do it in literally a year or more, so forgot.  Thanks!

Comment: Its a safety feature to prevent you from doing something bad to your system.  More or less the equivalent if SUDO in unix.